# Use K8s Ingress with Istio gateway?

Tags: istio

in the helm values file there is a setting global.k8sIngressSelector with the description.

> Gateway used for legacy k8s Ingress resources. By default it is
>   using 'istio:ingress', to match 0.8 config. It requires that
>   ingress.enabled is set to true. You can also set it
>   to ingressgateway, or any other gateway you define in the 'gateway'
>   section.

My interpretation of this is that the istio ingress should pick up normal ingress configurations instead of having to make a virtual service. Is this correct? I tried it and it is not working for me.

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo
          image: mendhak/http-https-echo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: echo
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
```

this works

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - '*.dev.example.com'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  hosts:
    - echo.dev.example.com
  gateways:
    - gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: echo
```

this doesnt

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  rules:
    - host: echo.dev.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: echo
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ingress needs to have an annotation: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio`.

Depending on what version of Istio you are using, it may not be working anyway. There is currently an open issue about Ingress not working in the latest drivers, and it sounds like it may have been broken for a while.

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10500

Comment: So I am understanding the intended functionality correctly, I just need the annotation. I'll try that, Thanks.

Comment: its working, Is there a way to set istio as the default ingress class. it is my only ingress.

Comment: can u share the complete yaml files for the solution? it seems it doesn't work in istio 1.1.1 https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/

Comment: Istio Ingress has been removed from Istio 1.1. See [release notes](https://istio.io/about/notes/1.1/#traffic-management)

Comment: @FreakinaBox Please share all files that worked for you. I am following the same but not worked.

Comment: @AshishKumar I am using the istio virtual services these days and don't have example files to share for doing it with ingress.

Comment: @FreakinaBox no worries, I got a solution. Now I am using networking strategy with plain Istio. 

Previously, I had tried to create hybrid networking architecture with AWS ALB(as a primary dns name) and Istio(Gateway to connect with AWS ALB, not with ingressgateway i.e; Istio with no Classic LoadBalancer dns name).

FYI- https://medium.com/@cy.chiang/how-to-integrate-aws-alb-with-istio-v1-0-b17e07cae156